# Ошибка "ORA-00600 [qcsfbdnp:1]"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qcsfbdnp:1], [B14], [], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>
> ORA-06512: at "IJJ_DF.RUY_REPORT_PCK", line 14627
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Что это означает? Ошибка появляется при выполнении процедуры PLSQL.
Причем функция работает нормально и падает только при добавлении в запрос `select` еще одного `left join`.

Выглядит код примерно так:

```
procedure ....

begin 

...

open p_res for
    with q1 as (
        ...
    )
    ....
    qGgg as (
        ...  
    ) 
    select ...
    from ....
    ...
    left join qGgg
    on ...

    ...
end;
```

Ошибка появляется при добавлении еще одного left join в условие запроса. Полностью код не привожу так как он очень большой. Если вырезать из кода запрос select и запускать просто в sql developer, то отрабатывает без проблем.
Версия oracle 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Внутренняя ошибка оракла. Лично у меня встречалась в рекурсивных CTE при попытке использовать рекурсивную выборку второй раз. По документации использовать второй раз - нельзя. Но так же ошибка может встречаться при любых других условиях - это внутренняя ошибка ядра Oracle, возможно баг. Единственный выход (кроме обращения в поддержку Oracle) - полностью изменить подход к получению нужных данных, переписать запрос начисто, зайдя как нибудь с другой стороны

Comment: И кстати, возможно сам запрос то отработал бы и в pl/sql если бы был в чистом виде, а вот внутри курсора или из за последующих действий с  этим курсором что то идет не так

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [MOS (My Oracle Support)](https://support.oracle.com) описаны три известных "бага" для Oracle 11.2.0.3.X, из-за которых возникает `ORA-600 [qcsfbdnp:1]`:

```
Bug         Fixed                                           Description
21373076    12.1.0.2.160419, 12.2.0.1                       ORA-600 [qcsfbdnp:1], [sys_b_040] From Query with WITH Clause
19670108    12.1.0.2.3, 12.1.0.2.DBBP07, 12.2.0.1           ORA-600 [qcsfbdnp:1] from WITH clause query with binds
13496884    11.2.0.3.6, 11.2.0.3.BP16, 11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1   ORA-600 [qcsfbdnp:1] from Merge Statement with Bind Variables
```

Все три связаны с использованием `bind variables`.
Первые два "всплывают" только при использовании конструкции `WITH ...` совместно с `bind variables`.

Больше всего под ваш случай подходят первые два.

Варианты решения:

- upgrade to 12.1.0.2.160419+
- отказаться от использования `WITH ... CLAUSE`
- отказаться от использования `bind variables`

На всякий случай напомню: аргументы (параметры) как и локальные переменные в процедурах PL/SQL, используемые в запросе тех же процедур, отрабатывют как `bind variables`